# Is it possible to grab a snapshot from a previously recorded video on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, frame, windows-phone-7.1, snapshot

I'd like to know if it's possible to grab snapshots from previously recorded videos. Those videos are recorded in the app itself.

By the way, I'd like to grab the snapshot from a video file saved in IsolatedStorage without having to play the video.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Cheers,
Rafael

Comment: Nothing, to be honest. I've done some research but haven't found anything that could do the job. I know it's possible to get the frame from a currently playing video via MediaElement, but i'd like to get the frame directly from the video file, like on Android, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the thumbnail while recording the video (captureSource.CaptureImageAsync()). To do that, I used the same instance of the CaptureSource I'm using to record the video.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an official platform feature to do this. However, if the video file is within your app's isolated storage, you might be able to:

- Send the video to a server to do the processing
- Add codecs/C# code to your app to process the raw MPEG4 frames.
- Try using WriteableBitmap to capture a specific frame when using the media element. Since most media is handled in hardware, however, it is possible that the frame will be blank.